# How do I Call Microsoft Teams OnlineMeeting endpoints via Microsoft Graph API using a console app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have followed the code example given in the following [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph/daemon-console) by Microsoft and was successfully able to get the list of users.

My registered app in the Azure Active Directory also have the "OnlineMeeting.ReadWrite.All" application permission.

But when I am trying to call the create meeting call by posting the request in the endpoint "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings". I am getting a 403 forbidden error. Any idea why I am getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the graph api create online meetings `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings`, we can see the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) shows it doesn't support "Application permission" to call it. It just support "Delegated permission", so we can just request it by password grant flow but not client credential flow.

[image]

**Update:**

For your requirement to request the graph api of creating online meeting, we can just use password grant flow or auth code flow. Here provide a sample of password grant flow(username and password) for your reference, use this sample to get the token and request the graph api by this token. You can also find this sample in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet#username-and-password).

```
static async Task GetATokenForGraph()
{
 string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.com";
 string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
 IPublicClientApplication app;
 app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
       .WithAuthority(authority)
       .Build();
 var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

 AuthenticationResult result = null;
 if (accounts.Any())
 {
  result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .ExecuteAsync();
 }
 else
 {
  try
  {
   var securePassword = new SecureString();
   foreach (char c in "dummy")        // you should fetch the password
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // keystroke by keystroke

   result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes,
                                                    "joe@contoso.com",
                                                     securePassword)
                      .ExecuteAsync();
  }
  catch(MsalException)
  {
   // See details below
  }
 }
 Console.WriteLine(result.Account.Username);
}
```

Comment: hi Hury, thanks for your answer. From your answer it is clear that I can not  use app only flow to create meeting. Now since my requirement is to create a meeting from daemon. What do you suggest would be an alternative approach?

Comment: Hi @TikluGanguly For request this graph api, we can just use password grant flow or auth code flow. Please refer to the "Update" in my answer.